# getting hasMany records of a HABTM relationship

Tags: php, cakephp

I have tables: `categories` HABTM `sculptures` hasMany `images`

from the `CategoriesController#find()` produces an array like so:

```
array(
    'Category' => array(
        'id' => '3',
        'name' => 'Modern',
    ),
    'Sculpture' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '25',
            'name' => 'Ami',
            'material' => 'Bronze',
            'CategoriesSculpture' => array(
                'id' => '18',
                'category_id' => '3',
                'sculpture_id' => '25'
            )
        ),
         (int) 1 => array(
                'id' => '26',
                'name' => 'Charis',
                'material' => 'Bronze',
                'CategoriesSculpture' => array(
                    'id' => '19',
                    'category_id' => '3',
                    'sculpture_id' => '26'
                )
            )
    )
)
```

I'd like to be able to get the images related to sculpture in the array as well if this is possible?

Comment: Take a look at `ContainableBehavior`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CakePHP's [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).  After reading about it and following the instructions, your find should look something like this:

```
$this->Category->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Sculpture' => array(
            'Image'
        )
    )
));
```

In your Category model, you need:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
public $recursive = -1; //can set this in many places, but it must be -1 for the Containable find to work.
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do this is to set recursive to 2 when you call `find()` ([example](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model#method-Modelfind)).  This will tell `find()` to connect all the associated models as well as the model associated with the associated models.

However, this approach can cause your dataset to grow quite large so a better approach is to use the [containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations) when including deeper associations.